# AWS ECS deployment Error using Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I created a jenkins job runing inside account A that connects using cross accounts IAM roles to account B, where we have a ECS cluster.
I manageg to build and upload the docker images from account A jenkins to account B, but when I use:

```sh
aws ecs update-service --cluster arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:Account_B_ID:cluster/Cluster --service cluster-service --force-new-deployment --region eu-west-1
```

I was promted by an error:

```sh
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Identifier is for AccountID_B. Your accountId is AccountID_A
```

I have checked the [Update-Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html) documentation, but i don't find any mistake and I cant found anything more regarding this issue anywhere.

Do you know where/how is the correct way of ECS cross account deployment?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Jenkins runs the `aws ecs update-service` command, right?

Comment: Yes, it's that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command with a CLI `--profile` which assumes the IAM role on `account-B`:

`aws ecs update-service --profile account-B_roleName`

In `~/.aws/config`:

```
[profile account-B_roleName]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::808449698514:role/PowerUser
```

You can only apply a command on a resource in an account with an (assumed) role or user which is defined in that account.

Comment: Thanks so much!; I have to admit that I already used the "--profile" in other commands, but I didn't notice it here.
And seems strange to me that anywhere was this explained as clear as you explained it here. THanks!